# A tool to correct extension of MS excel files?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have hundreds of excel files, which all named as *.xls. But in fact, some of them are *.xls, some are *.xlsx, and some are *.xlsb. Is there a software to automatically recognize and correct the extension of each excel file?

Comment: Those are all correct extensions..

Comment: Yes, Excel can open those files, but it will pop warning when the ext is not correct.

Comment: How are they not correct? They are all native extensions. You aren't making sense

Comment: "The file format and extension of xxx don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?" You can try it by yourself. Just create a .xlsx file and rename it to .xls.

Comment: That is useful information to provide in the question - the extensions have been changed, not "they are wrong"

Comment: @Raystafarian, in fact the question is correctly stated. They all have the xtension xls but some should be xlsb...

Comment: @perreal "technically correct" doesn't make it a good question, a clear question or even an on-topic question. Details are useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think opening the file at question in Excel and probing the workbook's `FileFormat` property with VBA should do the trick. This should work because Excel automatically detects the file type correctly when you open it.

Since you have a lot of files I would recommend a VBA program to loop over all the files (best put them all in one folder). Then open them one after another, check the `FileFormat`, save the result somewhere and close the file again.

You could also rename the files in the loop depending on their file format.

You could use code like this:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestExcelFileFormats(ByVal strPath As String, Optional ByVal boolTestOnly As Boolean = True)
    Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim fileExcel As Scripting.File
    Dim wbkOutput As Workbook
    Dim shtOutput As Worksheet
    Dim wbkTestFile As Workbook
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strCorrectExtension As String

    Set wbkOutput = Workbooks.Add
    Set shtOutput = wbkOutput.Sheets(1)
    shtOutput.Name = "Output"
    shtOutput.Cells(1, 1) = "Filename"
    shtOutput.Cells(1, 2) = "Old Extension"
    shtOutput.Cells(1, 3) = "File Format"
    shtOutput.Cells(1, 4) = "New Extension"

    i = 2
    For Each fileExcel In fso.GetFolder(strPath).Files
        Set wbkTestFile = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
            Set wbkTestFile = Workbooks.Open(fileExcel.Path)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not wbkTestFile Is Nothing Then
            shtOutput.Cells(i, 1) = fileExcel.Path
            shtOutput.Cells(i, 2) = fso.GetExtensionName(fileExcel.Name)
            shtOutput.Cells(i, 3) = wbkTestFile.FileFormat
            Select Case wbkTestFile.FileFormat
                Case xlOpenXMLWorkbook:
                    strCorrectExtension = "xlsx"
                Case xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled:
                    strCorrectExtension = "xlsm"
                Case xlExcel3, xlExcel4, xlExcel5:
                    strCorrectExtension = "xls"
                Case xlExcel12:
                    strCorrectExtension = "xlsb"
                Case Else:
                    ' unknown file format - you probably want to add it to one of the above cases
                    strCorrectExtension = fso.GetExtensionName(fileExcel.Name)
            End Select
            wbkTestFile.Close False
            If strCorrectExtension <> fso.GetExtensionName(fileExcel.Name) Then
                If Not boolTestOnly Then fso.MoveFile fileExcel.Path, fso.BuildPath(fileExcel.ParentFolder, fso.GetBaseName(fileExcel.Name) & "." & strCorrectExtension)
                shtOutput.Cells(i, 4) = strCorrectExtension
            End If
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next fileExcel

    wbkOutput.Activate
End Sub
```

Before you do some actual renaming call this procedure with the second parameter set to `True` (the default). This will just output a list of what the program `would` do if you set the second parameter to `False`.

And you should definetely verify the `Case`es with the [file format constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx) first. Verify that they are correct and add the ones that are missing.

Comment: Will Excel pop up warning when the program open each file named incorrectly?

Comment: @Jfly: What do you mean? If a file couldn't be opened (because it is of an unknown filetype) it just skips the file. Excel files with a differing extension than configured in the `Select Case` will be marked accordingly in the output. But just look at the code, everything is there. Also: I just fixed a small bug in the code where the last header was misplaced.